# When I move one bone everething of objects moves. | Blender

Tags: bones

I recently created a character from among us according this turtorial on youtube: [turtorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HxK4zopuTFo&t=311s), I tried to move with legs (bones of leg) as well, but when I move one bone everything from character moves **including the other leg**. Please help me.
Pictures:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: hello, please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I shared it ...

Comment: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/prvKSR1B

Answer (score 0):

Select your mesh and in the *Viewport Overlays* panel, enable the *Face Orientation* option, you'll see that the normals are flipped (they are red). In *Edit* mode, select all and press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> > *Recalculate Outside*, then parent again:

[image]

Comment: OMG, you are the best. Thanks a lot. It helped. How did you figure it out?

Comment: this is one of the causes of bad parenting so I just checked  ;)